# Mschart gridlines not starting from zero

Tags: mschart, mirror, gridlines

In VS2010 VB I am using MSChart (.Net 4) and I have a FastLine chart with values from -2000 to 2000 for X axis and -20 to 20 on Y axis.

The interval for the gridlines in X axix is 250 and I need the gridlines to be "mirrored" from origin (i.e. -250, 250; -500, 500;...) but when I execute the applications always the first gridlines are -200, 50 and then -450, 300...

I tried using `StartFromZero = True` in the axes properties without success. Is there any way to force the gridlines to be symetric from the origin (zero) ?

Comment: you can try setting `ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing` property as per the point you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments. 
I solved this issue by setting the IntervalOffset of the Axis. This offset represents the offset of the first gridline from left of the chart (in the case of X axix) . By calculating the displacement required (myChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalOffset = myChart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum Mod yourIntervalValue) to reach 0 from left most value with the interval used, I was able to make the gridline in the middle of the chart to match the zero line. 
I hope it helps others.